# ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword. Please explain

Tags: sql, oracle

Why I am getting this error?
Where should I add the SELECT keyword?

```
CREATE VIEW norders 
AS N1 
    SELECT n_ame, AVG(purch_amt), SUM(purch_amt) 
    FROM Salesman, orders
    WHERE Salesman.salesman_id = orders.salesman_id 
    GROUP BY n_ame;
```

Comment: What's the `N1` supposed to be for? That's your problem.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: The link points to `SQL Server` so it is not necessary relevant for `Oracle` @marc_s. For `Oracle`  is good to know also the current limitations of the ANSI style, examples are mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66403519/4808122) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66462627/where-clause-conditions-in-sql#comment117503228_66462627)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem is that 'N1' . not sure what are you trying to do there but here is the right syntax:

but also never use comma to join

```
Create View norders AS
Select n_ame, Avg(purch_amt) avgpurch, Sum(purch_amt) sumpurch
From Salesman s
JOIN orders o
  On s.salesman_id = o.salesman_id 
Group By n_ame;
```

Comment: +one for the correct `join` syntax instead of the it-just-works (but for how long?) table enumeration.

Comment: Well, both syntaxes are *correct* @DávidLaczkó and BTW you should know that Oracle *transforms* the ANSI syntax in the *comma separated join* before the execution (you may check the result with `DBMS_UTILITY.expand_sql_text`), so there is no real thread of *but for how long*.